# Order by FIELD() for mysql in prisma

Tags: prisma

I need the output to be ordered in the same order as the parameters, in a query MySql it would look like this

```sql
SELECT * FROM your_table
WHERE id IN (5,2,6,8,12,1)
ORDER BY FIELD(id,5,2,6,8,12,1);
```

How can I do it using the prism?

Answer (score 1):

You would need to use [Raw Query](https://www.prisma.io/docs/concepts/components/prisma-client/raw-database-access) to achieve this, Order By `FIELD()` is not natively supported yet.

Here's a Feature Request for adding support for Order By Field: [#9708](https://github.com/prisma/prisma/issues/9708)